# Find methods and methods call of C program using a bash script

Tags: c, bash, sed

Given a C program, I need to count for every defined method the number of calls and the lines where it is called.

Ex.

```
 1: ...
    void a(){
    ...
    }

    void b(){
    ...}

    main(){
    ...
40: a();
41: b();
42: a()
43: }
```

Expected result:
method "a" is called 2 times; lines: 40. 42
method "b" is called 1 times; lines: 41

I think I can use sed, somethign like: `sed -n '/void/,/(/p' test.c`
But I don't know how to adapt it to take into consideration all available possibilities. Or maybe there is an easier way to get this result? Any ideas are well welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think a simple shell script will cut it, as it'll be hard to avoid false positives (e.g., `/* a(); */`). But even if you'd like to implement this yourself, you're probably better off using a scripting language like Ruby, Python or Perl that can provide you with more powerful tools for parsing and accounting.

Comment: I need to solve this using a bash script :)

Comment: The easiest way to solve it with a bash script is to have the bash script output the source code for a proper parser into a file, compile that file and run the resulting binary. Or to have the bash script fetch the package for an analyzer, install it and run it. This is not a problem that is suitable for a shell script, the C grammar is too complex to parse with one-liners.

Comment: use a grep. First part to extrat all function definition header (put in a temp file or in a first loop), second part, extract each "header" ( from temp file) call with a grep -n and a wc -l for total

Comment: yes, this may work. I'll try, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use an existing static call graph analyzer. See the [Wikipedia page for "Call graph"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph), specifically the list of free software static C call graph analyzers.